# Loading Xml files from class path in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xml-parsing

I am trying to load and validate xml files from a directory in the class path at startup of a Spring Boot application. I am seeing the following error which indicates that I am trying to load files using absolute path and not class path:

```js
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [converters/mapper.xml] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/opt/core/home/libexec/boss/core-service-2.0.0.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/core-api-2.0.0.jar!/converters/mapper.xml
```

Below is a code snippet that loads the files:

```js
..
@Autowired
public FieldsMapTypeConvertersRegistry(@Value("${core.files-location:converters}")
                                                   String mapperFilesLocation) {
        this.mapperFilesLocation = mapperFilesLocation;
    }

..

try {
            // ToDo we need to replace this when we enable multi-tenancy
            ClassLoader classLoader = ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader();
            ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(classLoader);
            Resource[] xmlResources = resolver.getResources(mapperFilesLocation + "/*.xml");
            for (Resource xmlResource : xmlResources) {
                File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(xmlResource.getURL());
                registerTypeConverter(file);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do stuff
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            //do stuff
        }
```

I think the issue is in this statement in the code above:

```js
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(xmlResource.getURL());
```

but I am not sure what other ways I can do that. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just wondering why you are using `ResourceUtils.getFile(xmlResource.getURL())` when `xmlResource.getFile()` is already available to get the File Handle. Ideally speaking, you should be catching the FileNotFoundException inside the catch block and checking the detailed message wrapped inside the exception.

Edit:

The exception is being thrown because the xml is not found in classpath at runtime. Most probably, the file `target/converters/mapper.xml` is not available.

Comment: Good question and yes I tried xmlResource.getFile() and I got the same error. I think the issue is using getFile whether using xmlReource or ResourceUtils.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Can you find where exactly the mapper.xml is there in target folder after you compile?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `MyService.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/file.xml");` and then create File from stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try using commons-io:commons-io:2.7 (Maven artifact) and use the following code:

```
InputStream inputStream = obj.getClass()
                                     .getClassLoader()
                                     .getResourceAsStream("converters/mapper.xml");
                                         
String data = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, "UTF-8");
```